# Insert element at NSMutableArray's end

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

I am loading an array from a web service and displaying them in picker and all works fine. My array contains random number of questions for every category of questions. Now what i want is that i wanna add one more entry "Your own question" at the end of array so that the last row of picker displays "Your own question". How can i do this

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UILabel *retval = (id)view;
    if (!retval) {
        retval= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
    }

   // retval.text = [idAndNameArray objectAtIndex:row];
    if([pickerType isEqualToString:@"picker"])
    {
        retval.text = [idAndNameArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else
    {
        retval.text = [quesArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    retval.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
    retval.numberOfLines = 3;
    return retval;
}
```

This code only displays number of rows(questions) fetched from the web service.

**EDIT 1:**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView
{

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if([pickerType isEqualToString:@"picker"])
    {
        return [idAndNameArray count];
    }
    else
    {
       return [quesArray count];
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Resolved by making another NSMutableArray with my custom object "Your own question" and then appending it with the array fetched from web service

```
NSMutableArray *customObj = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject: @"test"];
 [quesArray addObjectsFromArray:customObj];
```

Answer (score 1):

In `UIPickerViewDataSource`'s method called `pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:` return your array's count plus one value(`return arr.count+1;`), and in the method of `UIPickerVIewDelegate`that you have implemented return your label with the text when the `component` is greater than `arr.count-1` (`if(row>(arr-1)){//return the label with 'Your own question'}`). Good Luck!

**EDIT:**

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if([pickerType isEqualToString:@"picker"])
    {
        return [idAndNameArray count];
    }
    else
    {
       return [quesArray count]+1;
    }

}
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    UILabel *retval = (id)view;
    if (!retval) {
        retval= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)];
    }

   // retval.text = [idAndNameArray objectAtIndex:row];
    if([pickerType isEqualToString:@"picker"])
    {
        retval.text = [idAndNameArray objectAtIndex:row];
    }
    else
    {
       if(row>quesArray.count-1){
         retval.text = @"You own question";
       }
       else{
            retval.text = [quesArray objectAtIndex:row];
         }
        }
        retval.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
        retval.numberOfLines = 3;
        return retval;
    }
```

Comment: but i need to have only one component in picker

Comment: is this what you are saying.. if([quesArray count] - 1 > quesPicker.numberOfComponents)....?

Comment: Yeah, sort of, can you provide your code for `pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:` and `numberOfComponentsInPickerView:` so that I can understand you correctly?

Comment: crash..-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array

Comment: everywhere you use the array, you have to check if array has the object under index you are passing to it.